# Can we restrict the interpretation of ' belongs to' relation in set theory?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, alternative-set-theories

In axiomatic set theory, the relation ' belongs to' is undefined, subject to the restriction imposed by other axioms, for example, the Axiom of Regularity.
In common parlance, the notion of 'belonging to a set' predicates some property which is common to members of the set and members not in the set do not have the property.      'Belonging' to a set S can itself be considered to be the property which defines and is common to the members of S.
Further, the notion of an 'element' or 'point' P being a limit of a set S is that , no matter how small a ' neighborhood' of P we consider, there are infinitely many points of S in that neighbourhood.
It is plausible to assume that if infinitely many elements close enough to P ( but possibly not all) have the property of 'belonging to S', P itself has the property of ' belonging to S'.
In other words, we   add as an additional Axiom,
( by restricting the full scope of the Axiom of Specification) that all subsets of a set are  necessarily closed.
My question is: Has any axiomatisation of set theory along these lines been attempted, and if so, any reference to it.

Comment: Since every set is a subset of itself, does this amount to saying that all sets are closed?

Comment: What does it mean for an arbitrary set to be closed? It makes sense if you have a set of real numbers, or a set in a topological space, but what is the topology on the class of sets?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: Yes- the restrictive Axiom  presupposes the existence of neighbourhoods  and  limit points and so would apply to metric spaces only and possibly to sets equipped with some topology. The main motivation for this  is that while a ruler is a good physical model for a closed interval, there is no physical  model of an open interval. We divide into two a physical ruler of say 2cms at the point 1cm - the 'point 1 cm', is inseparable from ( belongs to)  both the pieces.

Comment: But a set can have lots of topologies. And they can agree or disagree on which sets are open and closed, etc. So, which topology is "the chosen one", and why that one?

Comment: The motivation is mainly arising from the thought that if infinitely many points of a set S are  arbitrarily close( by whatever definition of closeness we have) to a point P, and because infinite precision is not possible physically, we may end up saying that P itself belongs to S.  So the definition of 'closeness' could be as we wish it to be.